# Using AmScope MU series camera with Python

Tags: python, camera

Does anyone have any experience trying to use an AmScope camera in Python?

I'm using MU1003 AmScope camera using a Python program using the toupcam SDK which is supposed to also work with the AmScope cameras.

I wrote some code around this [toupcam project](https://github.com/NMGRL/toupcam) but was unable to get a connection. In order to check that it wasn't an issue with compatibility, I tried to run this [AmScope camera](https://github.com/node-/CameraWorkbench) project but encountered the same issue. The connection issue can be traced back the calls in the toupcam.dll - **Toupcam_Open** and/or **Toupcam_OpenByIndex** both of which are always returning a null pointer. I have tried passing index values of **None**, **0**, **1** and **2** but always encounter the same error.

This issue has been replicated on multiple Windows PCs, both of which recognize the camera as a USB device named "USB3.0 Camera". The camera works because the "AmScope" program available on the [AmScope website](https://amscope.com/pages/software-downloads) launches and shows an image.

Any help on how to communicate with this camera in Python would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if the issue is that I don't have the correct .dll files for the camera, or if I need to pass a specific value for the index or if its something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amscope's MU1003 camera is the equivalent of ToupTek's U3CCD camera. You have to reach out to ToupTek's technical support and they will send you the correct SDK. Amscope is the reseller and doesn't have access to the SDK.